# Create a new table with existing style from layer_styles table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.3

Is there any way to create a postgis table with existing style from layer_styles table? Say for example i have so many styles stored in layer_styles table. I need to assign one of the style from layer_styles table to the new table which i am going to create. Can that be done using postgresql during table creation using sql command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the layer IDs of interest (or name, or any column you want) and to create the new table using this data+structure. However using the style in this secondary table may not be that easy

```
create table public.layer_styles_2 as 
    (select * from public.layer_styles where id in (2,3));
```

Comment: thanks. i did inserting into layer_styles table based on id and that worked.